# Hide div on save page (ctrl S)

Tags: html

If I wanted to keep data that cannot be copied outside of the html page, is it possible to hide a certain div on save page (CTRL+S) or via the menu? Thank you!

Comment: you can use javascript to listen to keystrokes and when CTRL + S is hit then hide it with JQuerry.

Comment: Hiding it won't be enough, it'll still be in the DOM. If it has sensitive information, I recommend removing it from the DOM temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `keydown` event with JavaScript and remove element if user press CTRL+S and element will be removed just before page is saved.
You can run this snippet below and click on field with two div and than try to press CTRL+S and element with `id="bb"` will be removed

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
 if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
  var CharCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()
  if(CharCode == "s") {
   $("#bb").remove();
   //alert('ctrl-s');
   //event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="aa">Div to stay</div>
<div id="bb">Div to HIDE on CTRL+S</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there is no listener when page is saved, which means the element which is removed can't be returned. Maybe with some timeout action
And you can't bind save action from browser menu with JavaScript.